# Conditional subtraction from multiple cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets

```
A    |B    |C    |....|K    |L    |M    |
Tom  |0    |     |....|Tom  |Jim  |Dave |
Jim  |1000 |     |....|15000|14000|12000|
Dave |3000 |     |....|     |     |     |
```

Using Google Sheets for this one. I would like the values in columns `K`, `L`, and `M` to read from column `B`, detect if the corresponding cell from `A` reads one of 'Tom', 'Jim', or 'Dave' for example, and then subtract the amount from the correct column to reduce a running total. I've had some trouble figuring it out and tried to use conditional formatting to solve it but can't seem to quite get there. Is there a formula I can use that will read column B and subtract the amount shown from the correct column based on the name in column A?

So to pseudo-code it:

```
read(column B cell);
if(column B cell - 1 column = "Tom")
{
column K - (value of column B cell)
}

else if(column B cell - 1 column = "Jim")
{
column L - (value of column B cell)
}
```

etc.

Is there a simple method I can use to generate this result? Also thought about changing the formatting of a cell based on the name in the cell next to it and subtracting the value of any cell with that colour but this becomes unwieldy if names are added. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the excel tag?

Comment: As far as I am aware the formula would be the same for wither piece of software but will remove the tag if it changes things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would there be a way to constrain the formula to a single cell so I can have the total in a single location rather than down the columns? My plan is to have the total boxes scroll with the sheet and always be visible.

Let's assume that Columns `A` and `B` continue on down the sheet, with further name + amount entries. You want to have a single row of balances for each of the people.

The balance is then some initial value less the sum of amounts for that person. Say the amounts you've shown in row 2 are the initial values; here's how you could have row 3 reflect the remaining balance for each person (This is for "Tom", copy for the others):

```
=K2-sumif($A$2:$B,"="&K$1,$B$2:$B)
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Alternative solution

*This doesn't do exactly what you want, but it is more appropriate for a running total scenario, so others may find it useful to adapt to ledgers, etc.*

The `IF()` function can be used to decide whether or not a value in Column B applies to one of the "total" columns, `K` to `M`.

Use this formula in `K3`, copy to the rest of the range:

```
=K2-if($A2=K$1,$B2,0)
```

[image: screenshot]

This example is in Google Sheets, but the same formula works in Excel and other "compatible" offerings.

Comment: This is great and does the job! But would there be a way to constrain the formula to a single cell so I can have the total in a single location rather than down the columns? My plan is to have the total boxes scroll with the sheet and always be visible. Alternatively, Is there a way to create a 'blank' cell if the conditions aren't met? I have tried:

`=K2-if($A2=K$1,$B2,"")`

But as I am dealing with integers it evaluates to an error as the text input doesn't parse to an integer

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Excellent answer presented excellently. Works a charm ;) Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you do is put the formula in each column.
Column K subtracts value of column B if column A = "Tom"
Column L subtracts value of column B if column A = "Jim"
etc

Comment: That makes sense and a far less complicated approach it seems. But how would I ensure it only subtracts values that appear to the right of 'Tom' for example? So:

   `if(column A = "Tom")
    {
    column K - cell to right of "Tom"
    }`

Comment: But you always have the name in column A and the value in column B, right?

Comment: Yup, that never changes but I need to specify that the totals are only subtracted on a 'Tom' row from the 'Tom' total if that makes sense